# Leveling taking ages in WoW, any tips?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> I have a level 29 Orc hunter if that helps, no one to play with

Answer (score 1):

It's meant to be hard to level up, so users could set a goal to get to a high level and spend a lot of time on the game and get a good experience but heres some ideas

If you bring a user (recruit a friend) on to Warcraft you get 3x exp which will help you level up really quickly

Also when you log out be in a inn or like a main city, that way you get more rest XP

Doing quests on your own means you don't need to share exp

Just some ideas :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Might try and rectuit my friend. Is the 3x exp forever or is it temporary?

Comment: @RavingGamer: The triple exp lasts for 90 days and only while you are under level 85. You also need to be within 100 yards of each other and nomore than 3 levels above them (If one of you is too high a level, only the lower-levelled character will get the triple experience)